# Is there a legend for figure 15 in the Airman Knowledge Test Supplement for Instructors?

Tags: faa-knowledge-test

Here's why I'm asking. While using King's free practice test tool, I ran into a question:
[image: a question]

about figure 15:[image: figure 15] in the Instructor test supplement asking about the percentage values for the MID area. I would just memorize the answer, but that's not a thing anymore, so I'm trying to find out where I can get the actual information. It seems like convective outlooks and "TSTM" outlooks are different things, as I have found both on NOAA's website. AC 00-45H only talks about convective outlooks, and doesn't even tell you the percentage values. I found [this](https://www.spc.noaa.gov/misc/SPC_probotlk_info.html) on the website that breaks it down.

But, that's not for the chart in the test supplement. The [closest thing I found on NOAA's website](https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/exper/enhtstm/) now just shows the percentage values directly on the chart, and they are very different from the answer choices on this particular question.

I hope there is a legend somewhere staring me in the face and I've just missed it!

P.S. King says the answer is A.

Comment: I think this is a case of the test material lagging behind reality.  I suspect, and hope, the next issuance of the test materials will have a revision to the Categorical Outlook.